# Performance difference between left join and SQL subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, sqlperformance

The question might be trivial but still, what's the differences in SQL Server queries like this:

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.Value
 FROM [User] t1
 LEFT JOIN [UserStory] t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

vs

```
 SELECT 
     t1.*, 
     (SELECT Value FROM [UserStory] t2 WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id) 
 FROM User t1
```

First of all from performance POV.

I see no cases when the second option will be suitable since as I can see for each record in t1, the server should call a separate query against t2 and I guess it's hard to optimize anything here.

Can someone comment on whether there are any cases where the second option with subquery might be preferable against adding a new table to join.

Added execution plan:
[image]

**Update**: If I'm reading executing plan correctly, the performance in both cases will be the same? (put aside possible error in case if subquery returns more than 1 record)

Comment: Have you consulted the query plans?

Comment: *If* there could be multiple related rows in `Table2` the second query would error.

Comment: it usually depends on Value. If it's a simple scalar like your example, there is no point. But for example `(select top 1 ...)` or `(select max())` could be harder to emulate using a LEFT JOIN

Comment: `Have you consulted the query plans?` - I'm not a big expert in it. It looks like a full index scan happens in both cases. 2 additional steps in the second case looks like not taking time? So no difference from performance POV?

Comment: `If there could be multiple related rows in Table2 the second query would error` - yeah, the record is always single

Answer (score 2):

> any cases where the second option with subquery might be preferable against adding a new table to join

The scalar subquery will fail if more than one row is returned.  So, that query contains additional information for the query optimizer and for a future developer who is trying to understand how the query works.

So, if you know that only one row will be returned, but that's not obvious from the table structure, the scalar subquery is preferable.

Comment: OTOH the assert operator added to throw an error if the subquery does return more than one row can limit the transformations available https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/scalar-subqueries/ba-p/383152#:~:text=GROUP%20BY%20clause.-,Performance,-The%20assert%20operator

Comment: Yes.  It's sort of a query hint, which should always be used with caution.

Comment: I know about failing if the result of subquery is more than one line, my question is mainly about performance

Comment: I added executing plan, and unless I'm reading it incorrectly, the actually taken steps will be the same?

Comment: Yes.  But the subquery forces the nested loops join.  The LEFT JOIN might use a different join strategy or join order.  Look at the link @MartinSmith posted for details.

Comment: I'm surprized that sub query can be an option here. It looks like even if similar subqueries to the same table like to calculate Field1: `SELECT.. WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Option1=t2.Option1` and Field2: `SELECT .. WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Option2=t2.Option2`, but with different condition options called more than once, still gives similar execution plans as join (like `.. left join t2 on t1.Option1=t2.Option1` and `.. left join t2 on t1.Option2=t2.Option2`